# git commit error: invalid commit message

Tags: git

I've been searching Google and cannot find anything on this error.

Here is the full error:

```
git commit -m "update ui"                                        
INVALID COMMIT MSG: does not match "type scope: subject" ! was: "update ui"
Note: scope must be only letters.
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have a `commit-msg` [hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) on your system that is enforcing a format on your commit message. This is presumably company policy of some kind.

Comment: Correct. And in this case, the required format is `scope: message` where `scope` must be only letters (I am guessing no digits or whitespace).

Comment: Thanks, this was definitely the case.